# $a * x \equiv a \pmod n$ other than $x = 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This is probably a very basic question, but beeing new to modular arithmetic it's difficult to to search for an answer without knowing a name for the concept. So for given $a$ and $n$:

$$a * x \equiv a \pmod n$$

- Is there a name for such $x$?
- Is there an efficient method to find the smallest $x > 1$?
- Is there an efficient method to find many such $x$?

Comment: Never seen a name for it.  Your congruence is equivalent to $a(x-1)\equiv 0 \pmod n$ so all you are asking is that $n\,|\,a(x-1)$.

Comment: If $n$ is prime there are no solutions other than $x=1$.

Comment: @Blex Well no solutions except $x\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ i.e $x=1,n+1,2n+1\cdots$.

Comment: Oh yes! I should have been more precise. :)

Comment: I slightly edited the question to clarify that I am intrested specific $a$, one at a time.

Comment: See also my Remark in my  [linked answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2419061/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $a>0$ and $x>1$ such that $a x \equiv a \bmod n$ iff $n$ is composite.
Indeed, if $n=uv$ with $u,v>1$, then take $a=u$, $x=v+1$.

If $a$ is fixed, then the smallest $x>1$ is such that $a(x-1)=lcm(a,n)=\dfrac{an}{\gcd(a,n)}$.
Therefore, $x=1+\dfrac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$.

There is no standard name for such $x$. You might call it a *multiplicative identity for* $a$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that $a\cdot{}x\equiv{}a(n), \forall{}a$ then the name for such an $x$ is the "multiplicative identity", and so $x\equiv{}1(n)$. Moreover, any other such value $y$ for which $a\cdot{}y\equiv{}a(n)$
has the quality $y\equiv{}1(n)$.

Thus, to answer your second question, the smallest such $x$ is always $1$.

For your third question, any value $y$ for which $y=r\cdot{}n+1$, where $r\in{}\mathbb{Z}$, will satisfy $y\equiv{}1(n)$.

If, however, you are just interested in $a\cdot{}x\equiv{}a(n)$ for a specific $a$, then it boils down to being able to find an $x$ such that $a(x-1)$ is a multiple of $n$. (Note that $x=1$ satisfies that trivially.)

Comment: Not true that $x \equiv 1 \bmod n$. Try $a=x=3, n=6$.

Comment: You're right, but that's only true for that particular $a$, not $\forall{}a$ as I specified.

Comment: Also note the second question explicitly states the smallest $x$ such that $x>1$